# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version, found versions 28.0.0-alpha3, 23.2.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

[image: why there is such error]

my gradle is here:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.8.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.13.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

}
compileSdkVersion is 28 and targetSdkVersion is 28 I don't know where is problem.
any help will be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42729387/4316327 check this answer

Comment: I add com.android.support:support-v7:28.0.0 but it doesn't work. could you tell me how can I correct it?

Comment: Can you show your gradle log after using `gradle dependencies`?

Comment: `+--- com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.13.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.1 -> 28.0.0-alpha3
|    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.13.0 -> 1.8.0
|    \--- com.facebook.fresco:animated-base:0.13.0
` if the problem is here? @TruongHieu

Comment: try to add `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha3'`

Comment: It doesn't work @TruongHieu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174690/discussion-between-truonghieu-and-qinxin-zhang).